# I know HashSet Internally work as HashMap and HashMap internally

Tags: java, collections

I know `HashSet` internally work as `HashMap` and `HashMap` internally use `LinkedList` as FIFO etc. So my Question is when I insert values in `StudentRecord` class object in pattern like..

```
    StudentsRecord record=new StudentsRecord(1, "Pramod", "UNA");
    StudentsRecord record2=new StudentsRecord(2, "Pankaj","Lucknow");
    StudentsRecord record3=new StudentsRecord(3, "Santosh","Chennai");

    HashSet<StudentsRecord> set=new HashSet<StudentsRecord>();
    set.add(record);
    set.add(record2);
    set.add(record3);

    Iterator<StudentsRecord> iterator=set.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        StudentsRecord result=(StudentsRecord)iterator.next();
        System.out.println(result.getId()+","+result.getName()+","+result.getAddress());
    }
```

After this why my result does not follow FIFO or LIFO order pattern?
My Output is:

```
3,Santosh,Chennai
1,Pramod,UNA
2,Pankaj,Lucknow
```

Comment: As far as I understand, LinkedList is being used when collision occures

Comment: hi @Pramod Maurya, if you get your answer then mark it correct answer. So any other viewer can get proper solutions. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LinkedHashSet instead of HashSet. because LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentsRecord record=new StudentsRecord(1, "Pramod", "UNA");
    StudentsRecord record2=new StudentsRecord(2, "Pankaj","Lucknow");
    StudentsRecord record3=new StudentsRecord(3, "Santosh","Chennai");


    Set<StudentsRecord> set=new LinkedHashSet<StudentsRecord>();
    set.add(record);
    set.add(record2);
    set.add(record3);


    Iterator<StudentsRecord> iterator=set.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        StudentsRecord result=(StudentsRecord)iterator.next();
        System.out.println(result.getId()+","+result.getName()+","+result.getAddress());
    }

}
```

Comment: Not answering why? Please refer Tim B's comment below.

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) can be used for this purpose.

It is same as `HashMap`, except that when you `iterate` over it, it presents the items in the insertion order.

Basically it preserves the insertion order.

from `JavaDoc`

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashSet will preserve insertion order for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answers actually answered "why":

HashMap stores objects into buckets, and then only uses the lists in the bucket. This is how it is able to find objects fast, as it can go straight to the correct bucket and then only needs to scan the entries inside that bucket.

In this example 3. has been added into an earlier bucket than 2 or 3 and as a result comes back in a different order.

`HashMap` and `HashSet` should never be relied upon to provide any particular ordering. You can use `LinkedHashMap` to retain insertion order or `TreeMap` to sort the entries.